# How to handle a file_as_string (generated by Prawn) so that it is accepted by Carrierwave?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, prawn

I'm using Prawn to generate a PDF from the controller of a Rails app,

```
...
respond_to do |format|
  format.pdf do
    pdf = GenerateReportPdf.new(@object, view_context)
    send_data pdf.render, filename: "Report", type: "application/pdf", disposition: "inline"
  end
end
```

This works fine, but I now want to move GenerateReportPdf into a background task, and pass the resulting object to Carrierwave to upload directly to S3.

The worker looks like this

```
def perform
  pdf           = GenerateReportPdf.new(@object)
  fileString    = ???????
  document      = Document.new(
    object_id: @object.id,
    file: fileString )
    # file is field used by Carrierwave 
end
```

How do I handle the object returned by Prawn (`?????`) to ensure it is a format that can be read by Carrierwave.

`fileString = pdf.render_file 'filename'` writes the object to the root directory of the app. As I'm on Heroku this is not possible.

`file = pdf.render` returns `ArgumentError: string contains null byte`

`fileString = StringIO.new( pdf.render_file 'filename' )` returns `TypeError: no implicit conversion of nil into String`

`fileString = StringIO.new( pdf.render )` returns `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: File You are not allowed to upload nil files, allowed types: jpg, jpeg, gif, png, pdf, doc, docx, xls, xlsx`

`fileString = File.open( pdf.render )` returns `ArgumentError: string contains null byte`

....and so on.

What am I missing? `StringIO.new( pdf.render )` seems like it should work, but I'm unclear why its generating this error.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It turns out `StringIO.new( pdf.render )` should indeed work.

The problem I was having was that the filename was being set incorrectly and, despite following the advise below on Carrierwave's wiki, a bug elsewhere in the code meant that the filename was returning as an empty string. I'd overlooked this an assumed that something else was needed

https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to:-Upload-from-a-string-in-Rails-3

my code ended up looking like this

```
def perform
  s = StringIO.new(pdf.render)

  def s.original_filename; "my file name"; end

  document  = Document.new(
    object_id: @object.id
  )

  document.file = s

  document.save!
end
```

Comment: how did you account for this 'bug elsewhere in the code', then?  I'm facing a similar issue.

Comment: @dax I've added code to my answer above. give this a try and let me know how you get on

Comment: thanks for that, in the meantime i found [this](https://github.com/csquared/IMGKit#carrierwave-workaround) example from imgkit which is also working for me

Comment: Is there any alternate way of doing this? I need to pass a variable name to the original_name function, so this doesn't quite work for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

You want to create a tempfile (which is fine on Heroku as long as you don't expect it to persist across requests).

```
def perform
  # Create instance of your Carrierwave Uploader
  uploader = MyUploader.new

  # Generate your PDF
  pdf = GenerateReportPdf.new(@object)

  # Create a tempfile
  tmpfile = Tempfile.new("my_filename")

  # set to binary mode to avoid UTF-8 conversion errors
  tmpfile.binmode 

  # Use render to write the file contents
  tmpfile.write pdf.render

  # Upload the tempfile with your Carrierwave uploader
  uploader.store! tmpfile

  # Close the tempfile and delete it
  tmpfile.close
  tmpfile.unlink
end
```

Comment: This works very good! The only problem is that a weird hash is added at the end of the file name, something for example: [realFilename].pdf20160803-42256-1ja9w8d

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way you can use StringIO like Andy Harvey mentioned, but without adding a method to the StringIO intstance's eigenclass.

```
class VirtualFile < StringIO
  attr_accessor :original_filename

  def initialize(string, original_filename)
    @original_filename = original_filename
    super(string)
  end
end

def perform
  pdf_string    = GenerateReportPdf.new(@object)
  file          = VirtualFile.new(pdf_string, 'filename.pdf')
  document      = Document.new(object_id: @object.id, file: file)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This one took me couple of days, the *key is to call `render_file` controlling the filepath so you can keep track of the file*, something like this:

in one of my Models e.g.: `Policy` i have a list of documents and this is just the method for updating the model connected with the carrierwave e.g.:`PolicyDocument < ApplicationRecord mount_uploader :pdf_file, PdfDocumentUploader`

```
def upload_pdf_document_file_to_s3_bucket(document_type, filepath)
  policy_document = self.policy_documents.where(policy_document_type: document_type)
                        .where(status: 'processing')
                        .where(pdf_file: nil).last
  policy_document.pdf_file = File.open(file_path, "r")
  policy_document.status = 's3_uploaded'
  policy_document.save(validate:false)
  policy_document
  rescue => e
    policy_document.status = 's3_uploaded_failed'
    policy_document.save(validate:false)
    Rails.logger.error "Error uploading policy documents: #{e.inspect}"
  end
end
```

in one of my Prawn PDF File Generators e.g.: `PolicyPdfDocumentX` in here please note how im rendering the file and returning the filepath so i can grab from the worker object itself

```
  def generate_prawn_pdf_document
    Prawn::Document.new do |pdf|
      pdf.draw_text "Hello World PDF File", size: 8, at: [370, 462]
      pdf.start_new_page
      pdf.image Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'images', 'hello-world.png'), width: 550
    end
  end

def generate_tmp_file(filename)
   file_path = File.join(Rails.root, "tmp/pdfs", filename)
   self.generate_prawn_pdf_document.render_file(file_path)
   return filepath
end
```

in the "global" Worker for creating files and uploading them in the s3 bucket e.g.: `PolicyDocumentGeneratorWorker`

```
def perform(filename, document_type, policy)
 #here we create the instance of the prawn pdf generator class
 pdf_generator_class = document_type.constantize.new
 #here we are creating the file, but also `returning the filepath`
 file_path = pdf_generator_class.generate_tmp_file(filename)
 #here we are simply updating the model with the new file created
 policy.upload_pdf_document_file_to_s3_bucket(document_type, file_path)
end
```

finally how to test, run `rails c` and:

```
the_policy = Policies.where....
PolicyDocumentGeneratorWorker.new.perform('report_x.pdf', 'PolicyPdfDocumentX',the_policy)
```

**NOTE:** *im using meta-programming in case we have multiple and different file generators, `constantize.new` is just creating new prawn pdf doc generator instance so is similar to `PolicyPdfDocument.new` that way we can only have one pdf doc generator worker class that can handle `all` of your prawn pdf documents so for instance if you need a new document you can simply `PolicyDocumentGeneratorWorker.new.perform('report_y.pdf', 'PolicyPdfDocumentY',the_policy)`*

:D

*hope this helps someone to save some time*