# Saving image created with RMagick using Rails and CarrierWave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image-processing, carrierwave, image-uploading

In my Rails app I have a module that takes several images, and using RMagick "stitches" them together into a new single image. I'm able to successfully create the final image, but **I'm having trouble saving this new image as an attachment to a model (using CarrierWave)**. The method that does the stitching looks like this:

```
def generate_collage(params)
    final_image = ImageList.new

    # ... code that puts together the composite image ...

    return final_image.append(true).to_blob { |attrs| attrs.format = 'JPEG' }
end
```

I've got my User model with an uploader mounted:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    mount_uploader :image, UserImageUploader
end
```

In the CarrierWave documentation under [the ActiveRecord section](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#activerecord), they show how to assign a new image, but they assume the file already exists somewhere. In my case it doesn't yet exist on the filesystem, and I'm outputting a `blob`... **is there any way to go from that blob to generating an image upload for CarrierWave**?

I suppose I'm trying to avoid saving this image temporarily into `"#{Rails.root}/tmp/"` and then reading it from there... it seems like I could cut out this step and send directly to CarrierWave somehow, but I don't know how! Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

I'm working on something similar right now.  This should be possible, but an easy workaround is to save it to a temp file:

```
temp_file = Tempfile.new([ 'temp', '.png' ])

image.write(temp_file.path)

user = User.new
user.avatar = temp_file
user.save

temp_file.close
temp_file.unlink
```

I'm hoping to try to improve it to remove the file system dependency completely, by following the advice in one of these answers: [How to handle a file_as_string (generated by Prawn) so that it is accepted by Carrierwave?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31487710/how-to-handle-a-file-as-string-generated-by-prawn-so-that-it-is-accepted-by-ca)